# ReadAsMultipartAsync equvialent in .NET core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'am rewriting a .net 4.5 application to aspnet core 2.0 and I have a method that i have some problem updating:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/files/{id}")]
    public async Task<Person> Put(int id)
    {
        var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
        var fileStream = await filesReadToProvider.Contents[0].ReadAsStreamAsync();
        return _personService.UpdatePerson(id, fileStream);
    }
```

It seems that request no longer has Content, but body. Which is fine. But how how do i read the body if it is a MimeMultipart now?

I have looked into IFormFile, but don't I have to change something in the frontend?

Anything that will help me in the right direction is appreciated :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.0) ... mainly the section of *Uploading large files with streaming*. It has to be something like

```
var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
    MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType),
    _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);

var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
```

Comment: Any full code sample? I need to save the file in a folder on my hdd, but the Microsoft sample doesn't have that code

Answer (score 2):

## Use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

You can install https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client

Then `ReadAsMultipartAsync` will be available as an extension method in .NET Core 2.

Ref: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18848

Sample usage: https://github.com/ringcentral/RingCentral.Net/blob/926f8e33a56f78c20223926a7cef7d4c9ada09b7/RingCentral.Net/BatchOperations.cs#L45

Comment: Could you please share an example or a link on how to use `ReadAsMultipartAsync` in .NET core?

Comment: @user2782405 sure, here you go https://github.com/ringcentral/RingCentral.Net/blob/926f8e33a56f78c20223926a7cef7d4c9ada09b7/RingCentral.Net/BatchOperations.cs#L45. The code is from RingCentral.Net which supports .NET Core. The usage is identical as in traditional .NET framework.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code! Is there a simple way to check MimeMultipart in the request or should I use helper class as mentioned in the above? If you don't mind, could you please share an example on how to check MimeMultipart in the request on .net core?