# ReadAsMultipartAsync is not available in net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know how I can replace this method.
I use NET.6 and Content and method ReadAsMultipartAsync are not available.

Example code:

```
private async Task<bool> readPart(MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider)
{
    try
    {
       InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = null;
        provider = await  Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new 
        InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider());

        ResumableConfiguration configuration = GetUploadConfiguration(provider);
                int chunkNumber = GetChunkNumber(provider);

        // Rename generated file
        MultipartFileData chunk = provider.FileData[0]; // Only one file in multipart message
                RenameChunk(chunk, chunkNumber, configuration.Identifier);

        // Assemble chunks into single file if they're all here
        TryAssembleFile(configuration);
                return true;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I mean this line

```
  provider = await  Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider());
```

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReadAsMultipartAsync equvialent in .NET core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368897/readasmultipartasync-equvialent-in-net-core-2)

Comment: it seems you are porting a ASP.NET Framework app to ASP.NET Core. That's needs rewriting, as much has changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like

```
 public async Task<ResponseDto> APIMethod([FromForm] DataType object)
```

this will read data from Form

and object contain something like

```
public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; } = new List<IFormFile>();
```

IFormFile will represent files that pushed to the server using Form